# Sendgrid API - Bad username / password error

Tags: php, sendgrid

I'm trying to send my first email with Sendgrid:

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('username', 'xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$email = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo("email1@gmail.com")
      ->setFrom("email@domain.com")
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
```

Here's the error I run into:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SendGrid\Exception' with message
>   '{"errors":["Bad username / password"],"message":"error"}'

Instead of 'username' and 'xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' I of course use real API key info from Sendgrid settings:
[image]

I used the long string key provided after creating the API key. But there still seems to be something wrong with this line:
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('username', 'xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

**Where should I get the info for authorization so that I don't get the Bad username / password error?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possible answer is to pass just the api key to the SendGrid() constructor;

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$email = new SendGrid\Email();

$email->addTo("email1@gmail.com")
      ->setFrom("email@domain.com")
      ->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun")
      ->setHtml("and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
```

Comment: If this also works and solves the problem I would HIGHLY recommend using this constructor because a) your full access username and password won't be in your code or possibly leaked and b) by using the API Key you can revoke a leaked key and also set much finer grained permissions.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the asker should only pass their SendGrid API key. By passing two strings, the SendGrid library thinks they're choosing to use an username and password instead of an API key.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 'username' which is the Name of the API Key, try using your SendGrid username (the username you use to log into the dashboard etc.).

EDIT: to make it work, also use Sendgrid password instead of API key. That worked for me.

EDIT 2: while this resolved the issue, one should use just the api key as mentioned in the selected answer.

Comment: I added another possible answer/solution too.

Comment: Please use the other answer/solution I provided. Thanks.

Comment: Found it. If you are using api way, just use accepted answer. If you are using smtp way, this is the correct answer. You should use sendgrid login username and password instead of api key for smtp username and password